# Twilio Video "Media connection failed" in Microsoft Edge

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I have the following code that runs without any issues in Chrome & Firefox, but will not run in Edge.
Error that comes up:

> Unable to connect to Room: Media connection failed

Can you please verify and confirm why it isn't working:

```
        let connectOptions = {
            name: roomIdentity,
            tracks: [localAudioTrack, localVideoTrack]
        }

        console.log(connectOptions)

        //creating stream for agent
        if (this.context.agent) {
            TwilioVideo.connect(twilioToken, connectOptions)
                    .then(room => {
                        //attach error handler to room object
                        room.on('disconnected', (room, error) => {})
                    }, error => {
                        console.error('Unable to connect to Room: ' + error.message)
                    })
```

**Edit 1:**
Fill error output:

```
code: 53405
description: "Media connection failed"
message: "Media connection failed"
name: "TwilioError"
stack: "TwilioError: Media connection failed at _getOrCreate (http://localhost:64000/static/js/1.chunk.js:322197:11) at Anonymous function (http://localhost:64000/static/js/1.chunk.js:322274:9) at Anonymous function (http://localhost:64000/static/js/1.chunk.js:97029:13) at flush (http://localhost:64000/static/js/1.chunk.js:91027:9)"
```

Comment: Can you share how you are getting the `localAudioTrack` and `localVideoTrack`?